# Uncaught Error: Template parse errors when added kendo-angular-scheduler into app.module

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I've added kendo-angular-scheduler into my angular app with this command:

`ng add @progress/kendo-angular-scheduler`

I have not used this module in my project (just installed).
After compiling code, I get the following error message in chrome console:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'toggleable' since it isn't a known property of 'button'. (" day of weekDays' kendoButton
                        [style.width.px]="75"
                        [ERROR ->][toggleable]="true"
                        [selected]="isSelected(day)"
                        (sel"): ng:///SchedulerModule/RecurrenceWeekdayRuleEditorComponent.html@8:24
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:215)
    at TemplateParser.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:14702)
    at JitCompiler.push../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate
```

What am I doing wrong?

and app.modules.ts:

```
/*angular modules*/
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { LOCALE_ID, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

/*custom modules*/
import { HubAdministrationToolModule } from './modules/hub-administration-tool/hub-administration-tool.module';
import { DashboardModule } from './modules/dashboard/dashboard.module';

/* custom routing modules*/
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app.routing.module';


/* library modules*/
import { GridModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-grid';
import { DateInputsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs';
import { UploadModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-upload';
import { PopupModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-popup';
import { SchedulerModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-scheduler';



/*custom components*/
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

/* Services */
//import { JWTService } from './authentication/jwt.service';
import { UtilsService } from './services/utils.service';

/* Custom Classes*/
import { ChartsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-charts';
import { IntlModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-intl';


import '@progress/kendo-angular-intl/locales/de/all';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import {AuthenticationService} from './services/authentication.service'
import { AuthService } from './authentication/auth.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

import { AuthGuardService } from './authentication/auth-guard.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent, AccessDeniedComponent, BadRouteComponent, RedirectComponent, LoginComponent, HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    /*jwtConfig,*/
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HubAdministrationToolModule,
    DashboardModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    GridModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    DateInputsModule,
    UploadModule,
    PopupModule,
    ChartsModule,
    IntlModule,
    SchedulerModule,


  ],
  providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE' }, /*JWTService,*/ 
    UtilsService,
    AuthenticationService,
    AuthService,
    JwtHelperService, 
    AuthGuardService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

before I installed other modules from kendo and all of them worked fine.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just updated `@progress/kendo-angular-buttons` package from 4.1.0 to 4.4.0 and it works fine.

run this command:

`npm i @progress/kendo-angular-buttons`

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure to import and export Kendo UI module where you are using it.

For example to use kendo UI Buttons

```
// Import the Kendo UI Component
import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';
```

and import **ButtonsModule** in your main module

Comment: I added `import { ButtonsModule } from '@progress/kendo-angular-buttons';`
into app.module.ts but I get a similar error.

Comment: As written in the post, I do not use this module. I have just installed and before I use this module, I get this error.

Comment: Check your html , if you used button component before importing it's module. Refer to this https://stackblitz.com/run/?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I've just updated `@progress/kendo-angular-buttons ` package from 4.1.0 to 4.4.0 and it works fine.